# Esperar un tiempo x luego de cada print en Python 2.7.15

Tags: python-2.7, time, print

hasta el momento mi código es algo como:

```
print "hola"
time.sleep(1)
print "mundo"
time.sleep(1)
if var == 0:
    print "hola"
    time.sleep(1)
    print "persona"
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    pass
```

y asi despues de cada print. La idea es lograr un "tiempo de carga" (ese no es el tiempo que utilizo, es un ejemplo.) pero el código es demasiado largo y, a demas de pereza, es molesto poner el `time.sleep(x)` a cada rato aún así sea un `def tiempo()`. Mi pregunta es si había algún método de poder hacer que python lo haga automaticamente después de una variable específica con un tiempo x determinado por mí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta hacer una función que reemplace al print y a esta ponle el timer, algo como:

```
def print_x(x):
    print x
    time.sleep(1)

print_x("hola")
print_x("mundo")
if var == 0:
    print_x("hola")
    print_x("persona")
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

El `pass` no hace nada más que evitar un error al poner `else:`, entonces puedes simplemente no poner nada de eso y dejarlo más compacto así:

```
def print_x(x):
    print x
    time.sleep(1)

print_x("hola")
print_x("mundo")
if var == 0:
    print_x("hola")
    print_x("persona")
```

Comment: responder solo con código se considera de baja calidad, revisa [answer] dale editar y añade una explicación

Comment: Gracias, arreglado

Answer (score 0):

Es como hacer un sistema propio de *logging*, puedes personalizar cada cosa del comportamiento que quieras a través de utilizar funciones u objetos. En este caso usé la práctica del diccionario.

```
from time import sleep

def print_delay(message, default_delay=1, message_category=None):

    time_opts = {
        'suspenso': 5, 
        'mucho_suspenso': 10
    }

    delay =  time_opts.get(message_category, default_delay)

    sleep(delay)
    print(message)

def main():
    print_delay('Mensaje 1', message_category='suspenso')        #Estos van a tardar 5
    print_delay('Mensaje 2', message_category='mucho_suspenso')  #y 10 segundos respectivamente
    print_delay('Mensaje 3', default_delay=2)
    print_delay('Mensaje 4')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Entonces, tu función de registros se puede mandar a llamar con un tiempo relacionado por un nombre (como el caso de "suspenso") o por un número, con un valor por defecto, en la entrada *default delay*